# My graph doesn't reflect the data created by VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a loop graph for each row of Excel. Everything is working fine until I spoted that my data wasn't reflected entirely right in the graph itself. For example, 92 percent and 8 percent on my barstacked100,
show near to an equal length for the both category. I linked a image of the example I tried moving the columns around and tried in both percentage and real number, nothing worked.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim work As Integer
    Dim chtObj As Shape

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "i").End(xlUp).Row
    work = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "j").End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To lastRow

        ws.Range(ws.Cells(x, "i"), ws.Cells(x, "j")).Select

        Set chtObj = ws.Shapes.AddChart2("", xlBarStacked, _
                                        Width:=200, Height:=40)
        chtObj.Left = ws.Cells(x, "l").Left
        chtObj.Top = ws.Cells(x, "l").Top

        With chtObj.Chart
            .Axes(xlCategory).Delete
            .Axes(xlValue).Delete
            .HasLegend = False
            .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Delete
            .Axes(xlValue).MinorGridlines.Delete
            .ChartTitle.Delete
            .ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = xlNone
            .ChartArea.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
            .PlotArea.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
            .PlotBy = xlColumns
        End With
    Next x
End Sub
```

[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSrAf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we can't see a sample file my answer is just speculation. In my opinion it is working, the problem seems like you are seeing the chart of a different row because the code is rendering the values in Row 2 in Row 3 and so on.

also remember that excel does not maintain the order, The chart will not be always rendered Column I value followed by Column J value. If this is the issue you might need to compare values and  change the values if the plot order the following is just an example.

```
.ChartGroups(1).SeriesCollection(1).PlotOrder = 2
.ChartGroups(1).SeriesCollection(2).PlotOrder = 1
```

Comment: Thank you Peh for you help! 

I found out another issue about it too. It's because the axis are on auto.

Thus I just used:
 .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScaleIsAuto = False
 .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScaleIsAuto = False

couldn't have solve it without you too, thank you and I really appreciate you help alot.